# Eclipse (Java SE) Installation Error without message

Tags: java, eclipse

I have installed these features on my PC (x64 OS), before strating Eclipse installation

[image: features]

With these defaults

[image: preparation]

And a minute later this message appears.

[image: error message]

What I do wrong and how can I install Eclipse Mars edition properly ?
(I use Visual Studio too, but I don't think its components are making conflict)

Comment: You are using the right version right? `64bit`/`32bit`

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention x64 windows 8

Comment: Check the architecture of eclipse[32/64]. If you are going to use 32 bit, use every software as a 32 bit architecture else use only 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "Run As Administrator" always makes problem. I run the installator through it and now it's fine. It's stupid, but I will leave it here If someone forgets about it too.